# Facebook app that automatically writes on fans wall, when some fan have birthday?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to create an facebook application for administrator of fanpage, that have functionalities for posting birthday greeting on their wall when particular fan or fans have a birthday?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: I don't think PHP allows that.

Comment: @Daan PHP's limitations have nothing to do with this. It'll be all about what the Facebook Graph API supports.

Comment: Yes its possible, though you havea  smallish time window when valid keys can be used, so you need to ensure you are signing in

Comment: @ceejayoz Haha true lol, I meant Facebook. What a weird day.

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried, but unfortunately this is out of my scope

Comment: @Pavlito So you decided to see if it'd be in our scope? We're not a free work service.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes. You are right. Tnx on your great help. Your experience with app is really helpful. Can I pay to you somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luckily, this is not possible, as it would be pure spam.

You would need to authorize every single User with the App, request the `publish_actions` and `user_birthday` permissions and store an Extended User Token (that is valid for 60 days). You will never get `publish_actions` approved by Facebook in their [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process, because it´s not allowed to autopost. Also, the message must be 100% User generated according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

TL;DR:

- Not possible
- Not allowed